# google CPU profiler error: stack trace depth >=2**32

Tags: google-perftools

I am trying to profile my program using the google CPU perf tools, but when I try to analyze the .prof file, I get an error like this:

```
At index 5519 (address 0126170):
node1.prof: stack trace depth >= 2**32
```

I thought maybe at first that it was trying to profile too many calls, so I reduced the length of my program run (timestep-based, so easy to make a shorter run) and I still got the same error. Any help getting around this would be much appreciated.